# Stop CocoaPods from resetting settings on install/update

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an installed pod ([CorePlot](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CorePlot), if it matters), which has a couple of documentation warnings that I silenced by setting Documentation Comments to No in the Pods project build settings, as well as a warning for Always Search User Paths which I also set to No in the CorePlot target build settings.

My problem is that every time I run `pod install` or `pod update`, it resets both of those settings to their original values and the warnings return.  Is there any way I can stop it from doing this?